# Распознавание символов

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети, распознавание

Добрый день!

Я пишу дипломную работу, тема - распознавание текста. На вход картинка с символом - на выходе распознанный символ. Программа реализована с помощью нейросети. На текущий момент умеет распознавать буквы, цифры, математ. символы.

Программа для дипломма должна нести в себе **инновационность.**

Я например вижу инновационность своей программы в том что она по сравнению с другими программами по распознаванию основанными на нейросетях(малоизвестные программы) - дает более менее неплохой результат...

Хочу обратиться к Вам:
**Как Вы считаете, что можно позиционировать как инновационность для моей программы?..**
Мне очень интересно услышать Ваше мнение...

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: >она по сравнению с другими программами по распознаванию основанными на нейросетях

Вот это повод задуматься, а тот ли инструмент вы используете.

Был бы я в вашей комиссии обязательно задал бы вопрос: "Чем обусловлен выбор способа построения модели для распознавания?".

Если не знаете ответа *такая новация выглядит как недоработка*.

Comment: Например инновационностью может быть, что заранее алфавит не известен, но известно, что он ограничен и текст на распознавание состоит только их этого алфавита.  
Программа, которая будет способна составить алфавит и распознать его будет инновационной :-)  
То, что Ваша НС будет распознавать лучше еще надо доказать :-)